# upload_max_filesize changed in php.ini file, but ini_get still shows 2M

Tags: php

I am no longer trying to change upload_max_filesize with ini_set.  I have seen those answers.

I found what I think is the real php.ini using the path from phpinfo().  I have edited the file changing the value from 2M to 10M.

In spite of this, ini_get('upload_max_filesize') still shows 2M and my upload is still failing because the file is larger than this.

What am I missing?

Comment: did you restarted apache after changing php.ini??

Answer (score 3):

There are four things to check if experiencing an issue like this:

1. Ensure that the correct php.ini is being loaded by using phpinfo()
2. Ensure that no extra ini files are being loaded via the [--with-config-file-scan-dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-scanned-files.php) option
3. That you haven't used ini_set() anywhere in your code to override the setting
4. That you restarted your web server after making any changes to ini files

Less commonly, you can also configure PHP to be run with the -d or [--define](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) directive which can set this setting at runtime.  This would also be shown in the phpinfo() results.

Comment: +1 "That you restarted your web server after making any changes to ini files".